# RuntimeError: Model class first_app.models.Topic doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

[image]**I am getting this following error when trying to run**

> RuntimeError: Model class first_app.models.Topic doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
[![from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length = 264,unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 264, unique = True)
    url = models.URLField(unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)][1]][1]
```

Comment: The problem is that you apparently import the `app.models` somewhere, before Django loads the models itself.

Comment: Did you add `first_app` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: sir, could you please help me I couldn't find out this problem I am trying to solve for 3 days

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is in *module* app:

```
first_app.apps.py
```

**Change:**

```
class First_appConfig(AppConfig):
          name = 'fist_app'
```

**To:**

```
class First_appConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'name_project.fist_app'
    verbose_name = 'Fist_app'
```

Hope this helps you! I had the same problem so I was able to solve it in a similar way.

Comment: In my case: verbose_name=.. was not required, but change in name=.. really solved the problem (ie. strange error above). But the `name_project` in my case was not the name of the project but `apps.` because I have all my apps in subfolder apps/. If I ommit `apps.` here, lot of things works but in case of admin change_form I had this strange error in typical django well descriptive style :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of your session, it looks like you did not add `'first_app'` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps). In your `settings.py` file, you need to add this:

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …
    'first_app',
]
```

Then you will need to rerun the `makemigrations` command, since now it could not find your `first_app`, and hence did not make any migrations at all.

Comment: how can I add like this sir, INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

Comment: @Rasel: did you wrote this to the `settings.py` file, and tried to make migrations again?

Comment: yup, sir but it's not gonna happen